# MIPS Multiplication with overflow follow by subtraction

Tags: mips

The result of multiplication is stored in two different registers in mips high and low.

For Example: in this example i take high and low as 4 bit register for the sake of convenience.

```
li $t0,12
mult $t0,$t0
```

12 * 12 = 144

1100 * 1100 = 1001 0000

so the high has 1001 and low has 0000. now if i want to subtract 12 from the result. how do i do that?

i cant use

```
mflo $t1
subi $t2,$t1,12
```

because low has all zeros and the result would be wrong.How do i perform subtraction in this case.when two numbers are 32 bit integers and multiplication causes an overflow.say something like
    2^30 * 2^4 - 14
the high register is used.

Comment: why is it wrong? 144 - 12 = 132 or 1000 0100 in binary

Answer (score 1):

MIPS registers are 32-bit (or 64-bit, but that does not change results in this case), so after multiplication you will have hi=`0x00000000` and lo=`0x00000090`. I.e. the 8 bits of product fit into 32 bits of `lo` just fine.

After subtracting 12 from 0x90 you should expect to see t2=`0x84`

Comment: i just gave 12 as an example because...it would cause an overflow in 4 bit multiplication.

Comment: There's no such thing as 4-bit multiplication on MIPS (or on most of the modern processors down to low-end 8-bit microcontrollers). All operations are done with 32 or 64-bit registers, even if your operand would fit in few bits. Result is also register-sized, so there's no overflow in your case.

Comment: @programer8  Are you asking how to subtract a number from a result that's in the hi/lo *pair* of registers? If that's the case, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940524/double-precision-integer-subtraction-with-32-bit-registersmips